# Optimized way to using map and join in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

Optimized way to show `name` from the array.

```
array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'abc'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'abc3'
  }
]
```

How can we make extract `name`,

```
abc, abc2, abc3...
```

I tried,

```
a.map(x => x.fullName).join('')
```

How can we add `...` after the length of the string is more than `15`.

I don't want to iterate over the whole array as I will not be showing all the names.

Comment: Use a simple for loop and if the string length is > 15 terminate the loop?

Comment: You need `a.map(x => x.name).join(', ')`. Adding ellipses can also be achieved using [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

Comment: `const b = a.map(x => x.name).join(', '); return b.length < 15 ? b : b.slice(0,15) + '...';`

Comment: Anyhow, using a map will iterate over the complete array. Which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I realized I misread your question. For your case a simple `for of` loop would more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`array.slice(0, 3).map(x => x.fullName).join(', ') + '...'`

This is the best-optimized solution. I can think of now.

Comment: This is wrong. What if the first 3 users have long names and the join returns 50+ characters?  Just use a `for..of` loop: `for (const { name } of array) { output += \`${name},\`; if (output.length > 15) { output = output.slice(0, 15) + '...'; break; } }`

Answer (score -1):

this can be done using .forEach of JS

```
let surnames = "";
array.forEach(obj=>{ surnames+= ` ${obj.name}`});
```

Comment: *"How can we add ... after the length of the string is more than 15"*

Comment: works well, here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/j9qpgbtw/